# I'm having a problem in reference to the Watson API is giving this problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson

Is giving error of authenticity when making the requests of this error that is in the photo link
error link => https://prnt.sc/to3ie5

Answer (score 0):

The error is a 403, indicating that you are using either an incorrect key or an incorrect endpoint. Most likely both are incorrect.